# result wasn't alphabetical order when i'm using a "sort function"

Tags: django, python-3.x

i'm a beginner and i'm wan't to do something here's my problem form DJANGO part 3 tutorial i put 3 questions and i want it to show but in a alphabetical order here's what i did.

the normal result is this:

```
bWhat's 02aWhat's 01cwhat's 03
```

```
    def index(request):
        latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:3]
        output = (''.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list]))
        output_list = list(output)
        output_list.sort()
        return HttpResponse(output_list)
```

and then i try to convert it into a list() to sort but here's what i got result:
    '''000123WWaaaabchhhssstttw

Comment: You created a single string of the items, and thus then you sort the *characters*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You constructed a single string with `''.join(..)`. That thus means that if you sort the list, you will sort the *characters* of the list.

You should drop the `''.join(..)`, like:

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:3]
    output = sorted([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
    return HttpResponse(output_list)
```

It is however strange to return a list of strings as the content of `HttpResponse(..)`.